# Saving CDATA with saveXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I wrote a short PHP script to grab an existing XML file, find a node and change it to a new value. New value must be wrapped into a CDATA block. This works fine, however the <> characters are replaced with their respective HTML entities. This ruins my XML validation in Java.

```
<?php
$fileName = "whatever";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('test.xml');
$doc->getElementsByTagName("SomeNode")->item(0)->nodeValue = "<![CDATA[".$fileName."]]>";
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$doc->save("test.xml");
echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

This is the source of the new test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
<FirstNode>
   <SomeNode>&lt;![CDATA[whatever]]&gt;</SomeNode>
</FirstNode>
</Root>
```

I really need the <> characters and not their HTML entities. How can I accomplish this?

UPDATE:
I used createCDATASection() as per suggestion, but it's not working when I try to save it as a node value (I just get a blank page). It works if I append it to the DOM, but that does me no good.

```
$cdata = $doc->createCDATASection( 'whatever' ));
$doc->getElementsByTagName("SomeNode")->item(0)->nodeValue = $cdata;
```

Comment: There is a function for that [`DOMDocument::createCDATASection`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php)

Comment: Thanks. That seemed like exactly what I needed....but it didn't work. I updated the question with results.

Comment: @VeryAttractiveS do not assign $cdata to nodeValue, but use appendChild, as per example in link by @ b.enoit.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your `test.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <FirstNode>
        <SomeNode>a</SomeNode>
    </FirstNode>
</Root>
```

You have two possibilities : 
Or you want add in SomeNode

```
<SomeNode>
    a
    <![CDATA[whatever]]>
</SomeNode>
```

Then you can do it like that :

```
$cdata = $doc->createCDATASection( 'whatever' );
$doc->getElementsByTagName("SomeNode")
    ->item(0)
    ->appendChild($cdata);
```

Or you want to replace in SomeNode

```
<SomeNode>
    <![CDATA[whatever]]>
</SomeNode>
```

Then you can achieve it like that :

```
$cdata = $doc->createCDATASection( 'whatever' );
$oldNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName("SomeNode")
               ->item(0);
$oldNode->parentNode
        ->replaceChild($cdata,$oldNode);
```

Comment: So close! This replaces the entire <SomeNode> entry with <![CDATA[whatever]]>.

Comment: Then read the answer again and use the first snippet of code.

Comment: I ended up clearing the value of the node first by adding `$oldNode->nodeValue = "";` and then using `appendChild($cdata)`. It's not really clear in the answer, but I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `DOMNode::$nodeValue` to write values, except for an empty string. Its escaping is broken. The "official" property for the text content of a node is `DOMNode::$textContent`.

Creating XML nodes has 3 steps:

1. create the node
2. append the node
3. modify the node (optional)

### Create the node

This depends on the node you want to create.

An element node:

```
$element = $document->createElement('nodename');
```

Or a text node:

```
$text = $document->createTextNode('<content>');
```

Or a CDATA section:

```
$cdata = $document->createCDATASection('<content>');
```

### Append the node

Now that you have a node you can append it to the document or a parent element node.

```
$document->appendChild($element);
$element->appendChild($text);
$element->appendChild($cdata);
```

The result of appendChild() is the appended node. So it can be combined with the create:

```
$element = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('nodename'));
```

### Modify the node

This is mostly done for element nodes. You can add attributes and child nodes.

```
$element->setAttribute('attr', 'value');
```

### Example

```
// create the document 
$document = new DOMDocument();

// create the document element node and append it
$element = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('nodename'));
// set an attribute on the element node
$element->setAttribute('attr', 'value');
// add a text node to the element node (escape <>)
$element->appendChild($document->createTextNode('<content>'));
// add a CDATA section to the element node (do not escape <>)
$element->appendChild($document->createCDATASection('<content>'));

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nodename attr="value">&lt;content&gt;<![CDATA[<content>]]></nodename>
```

## Modify existing XML

If you like to modify an existing XML you need to fetch the node first. The most efficient way for that is XPath.

It allows you to fetch the node. Like `DOMDocument::getElementByTagName()` it will return a node list, but it is a lot more specific and powerful.

### Example

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Root/FirstNode/SomeNode[1]') as $someNode) {
  $someNode->nodeValue = '';
  $someNode->appendChild($document->createCDATASection('<content>'));
}
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <FirstNode>
    <SomeNode><![CDATA[<content>]]></SomeNode>
  </FirstNode>
</Root>
```

`$someNode->nodeValue = ''`. removes all child nodes of an element. Here is no actual content so the escaping bug is not relevant. After the children are removed you can append a new CDATA section with the required content.

**Hint**: Try to use text nodes, not CDATA sections if possible. CDATA sections disable encoding/escaping features.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! The last example is exactly what I ended up doing (minus the use of xpath). I wish I could accept two correct answers.